# Select option in drop down list materialize css In selenium using java

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to select option in drop down list materialize css in selenium using java.
I am trying with id, but every time id changing.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.select-dropdown.active")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='select-options-db8c4be0-fa76-9286-bbef-80bde7193503']/li[2]/span")).click();
```

page source:

```
<div class="input-field">
    <div class="select-wrapper validate mandatory">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <input class="select-dropdown active" type="text" value="Organization Type" data-activates="select-options-465e6e55-1802-f0a6-4956-dafb1c063abc" readonly="true" tabindex="5" style="color: rgb(170, 170, 170);">
        <ul id="select-options-465e6e55-1802-f0a6-4956-dafb1c063abc" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown active" style="width: 465px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1; display: block;">
            <li class="selected">
                <span class="" data-target="">Organization Type</span>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <span class="" data-target="">Provider</span>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <span class="" data-target="">Billing Agent</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <select id="orgType" class="validate mandatory initialized" tabindex="5" name="orgType">
            <option value="">Organization Type</option>
            <option value="Provider">Provider</option>
            <option value="Billing Agent">Billing Agent</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its all about xpath creation. you may try like

```
 Xpath=//li[contains(text(),'Provider')]  or //div[@class='input-field']/div/ul/li[2]/span  or may others also
```

This helps you https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Comment: **//div[@class='input-field']/div/ul/li[2]/span** this is correctly selecting...thank u bro